# How to fix npm create-react-app Error in react.js?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to install react.js, during the creation of create-react-app, I got this npm ERR! "Cannot read properties of undefined (**reading 'isServer'**)." Can someone help me out how to solve this problem?.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69615175/how-to-resolve-reading-isserver-error-in-npm

Comment: I think you must have to re-install node and npm and try again. Hope it will work! Thanks.

Comment: Parth, Thanks for your respond. However, I did try that, but didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve (reading 'isServer') error in npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69615175/how-to-resolve-reading-isserver-error-in-npm)